# Sql Server 2016 errror Incorrect syntax near 'EXTERNAL'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, azure-vm

I have two SQL Server 2016 VMs in Azure. I am trying to connect these two sql server instances using External datasource. I can safely connect the two instances from my local pc, remotely.
While querying using external table/data source, I am getting this:
[image]

Kindly note

i) I have used both RDBMS/SHARD_MAP_Manager

ii) Credential is valid credential

iii) I know, i can use Linked Servers, but i don't want it. As i am planning to move these databases to Sql Azure Db. External Table and datasource is not mandatory. You can suggest alternatives other than LinkedServers.

So i need a query or part of query that will work with both, Sql Server(Virtual/Physical server) and Sql Azure(Db as a Service)

### Update

**Same query ran flawlessly on Sql Azure db.**

Comment: Elastic Database Query (External tables of type RDBMS or SHARD_MAP_MANAGER) is not supported on SQL 2016.  You can use linked server + synonyms to create a compatible schema between External Tables in SQL DB and SQL in a VM, although the DDL to create them will be different.

Answer (score 4):

`External data source` type `SHARD_MAP_MANAGER` and `RDBMS` is only supported only on Azure SQL Database v12 or later. It is not supported on SQL Server 2016.

Ref:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql

```
-- Elastic Database query only: a shard map manager as data source   
-- (only on Azure SQL Database v12 or later)  
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE data_source_name  
    WITH (   
        TYPE = SHARD_MAP_MANAGER,  
        LOCATION = '<server_name>.database.windows.net',  
        DATABASE_NAME = '\<ElasticDatabase_ShardMapManagerDb'>,  
        CREDENTIAL = <ElasticDBQueryCred>,  
        SHARD_MAP_NAME = '<ShardMapName>'  
    )  
[;]  

-- Elastic Database query only: a remote database on Azure SQL Database as data source   
-- (only on Azure SQL Database v12 or later)  
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE data_source_name  
    WITH (   
        TYPE = RDBMS,  
        LOCATION = '<server_name>.database.windows.net',  
        DATABASE_NAME = '<Remote_Database_Name>',  
        CREDENTIAL = <SQL_Credential>  
    )  
[;]
```